# Magento product price is zero, only on homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, price

The products on the category pages are doing fine, price is showing correctly.

On the homepage, I made an extra products list (via layout.xml block), which shows products from a specific category (category ID 40). Everything is doing fine, except for the price, which shows zero.

My `homepage.products.phtml` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     rwd_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
/* @var $this Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List */
?>
<?php

$category_id = 40;
$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id); 
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','url','small_image'));
$collection->addStoreFilter();          
$collectionSize = $collection->count();
$columnCount = $this->getColumnCount();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$i = 0;

?>

<div class="std">
<div class="widget widget-new-products">
<div class="widget-title">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Our tip for a fantastic trip!'); ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Experience it on board'); ?></p>
</div>

<?php
if(!empty($collection))
{ ?>
<div class="widget-products">
    <?php $collectionSize = $collection->count() ?>
    <?php $columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $columnCount; ?>-col first odd">

        <?php foreach ($collection as $product){ ?>
        <?php if ( $i < 4 ) { ?>

            <?php $productID = $product->getId(); ?>
            <?php $options = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($product); ?>
            <?php $qtyTotal = 0; ?>
            <?php $attrId = $product->getAttributeSetId(); ?>

            <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
                <?php foreach($option->getValues() as $_value): ?>
                    <?php $qty = $_value->getCustomoptionsQty() ?>
                    <?php if (!empty($qty)): ?>
                        <?php $qtyTotal += $qty; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

                <li class="item<?php if($i == 0): ?> first<?php elseif($i == 3): ?> last<?php endif; ?> item<?php echo $i; ?><?php if( $qtyTotal <= 0 && $attrId != 12 ): ?> full<?php endif; ?> attr<?php echo $attrId; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">

                        <?php 
                            $imgSizeWidth = 220; 
                            $imgSizeHeight = 152;
                        ?>
                        <div class="catalog-item-image" id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $product->getId(); ?>"
                            style="background-image:url('<?php echo $this->helper("catalog/image")->init($product, "small_image")->keepFrame(false)->resize($imgSizeWidth,$imgSizeHeight); ?>');">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if ( $product->getAttributeText('period') != '' ) { ?>
                        <p class="period-box">
                            <label class="label">
                                <?php $period = $product->getAttributeText('period'); ?>
                                <?php echo $period; ?>
                            </label>
                        </p>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <p class="price">
                        <?php 
                        // Check if attributeset is 'complete-ship'
                        if ( $attrId != 12 )
                        {
                            // If attributeset is not 'complete-ship', show normal price
                            if ( !empty($this->getPriceHtml($product, true)) )
                            {
                                var_dump($this->getPriceHtml($product, true));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo $this->__('Price on request'); 
                            }
                        } 
                        // If attributeset is 'complete-ship', and attribute 'price_request' it's not empty
                        else if ( $attrId == 12 && $product->getAttributeText('price_request') != '' )
                        {
                            echo $product->getAttributeText('price_request');
                        }
                        // If attribute 'price-request' is empty, and product is in stock
                        else if ( $product->getAttributeText('price_request') == '' && $qtyTotal > 0 )
                        {
                            echo $this->__('Price on request');                       
                        }
                        // If product is out of stock and attributeset is not 'complete-ship'
                        else if ( $qtyTotal <= 0 && $attrId != 12 )
                        {
                            echo $this->__('Out of stock');
                        }
                        // else
                        else {
                            echo $this->__('Price on request');     
                        }
                        ?>
                    </p>
                </li>
            <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php } ?>      
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">docReady(function() { decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last']) })</script>
</div>
<?php
}
else
{
    ?><p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p><?php
}              
?>
</div>
</div>
```

I copied most of the code from the `template > catalog > product > list.phtml` file.

The layout:

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="catalog/product_widget_new" name="home_products" before="follow_vessel" template="custom/homepage.products.phtml">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home_products</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

---

UPDATE

I have changed my block type to `catalog/product`, and it seems the error lies in this line:

```
$this->getPriceHtml($product, true)
```

Also, the console returns this error:

```
(index):136 Uncaught ReferenceError: Mage is not defined(…)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in another way like instead of loding priceHtml templatedirectly use final price of product and format that price according to need.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());

$productPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getFinalPrice(), true, false);
```

Comment: Also returns 0 :p

Comment: Pl check my updated answer

Comment: It does return the price, but without the extra stuff you normally get (for example the word 'from'). But if the other answers won't work, ill have to do it with this

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
 $productBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price');
```

use getPriceHtml

```
echo $productBlock->getPriceHtml($product);
```

Comment: Magento Has Its Own way to call helper, block and model class dont tell people to use `new`

Comment: yeah my bad practice

Comment: It seems this code doesn't work :/ It doesn't show the price and stops the code there

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code Init `BLock` class and use block class method.

Here your Template not pointing to `catalog/product` `block` and so that is why It is not able to find `getPriceHtml` method

```
 $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view');
 $block->getPriceHtml($product, true);
```

Comment: This code doesn't work :/ Doesn't display the price and crashes the process from then

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen Please check updated code

Comment: Now  $block = Mage:app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product'); is responsible for the crash

Comment: try with `Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product');` double `:: ` I forgot it sorry

Comment: Nope, I have also changed the block type to catalog/product, but it gave the same result... It seems the code crashes as soon as it hits $VARIABLE->getPriceHtml($product, true)

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen  check My updated Block Type

Comment: Also crashes the code :/

Answer (score 0):

Yes! So I combined the answers of Ashish and Gopal and did this:

At the top of the document:

```
$productBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price');
```

At the location where the price has to be generated:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
echo $productBlock->getPriceHtml($_product);
```

Thanks alot you two, I will surely upvote you guys!

Comment: why you are loading product again? You can remove  `$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());` Refer my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can change you collection like this :

```
$category_id = 40;
$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id); 
$collection = $catagory_model->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','url','small_image'));
$collection->addStoreFilter();          
$collectionSize = $collection->count();
$columnCount = $this->getColumnCount();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$i = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I copied most of the code from the template > catalog > product >
>   list.phtml file.

The Issue Is: *Your code left out the price portion.*

This is the relevant Code Path:

- app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml
- - $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
- Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::getLoadedProductCollection
- - return $this->_getProductCollection()
- Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_getProductCollection
- - $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
- Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::getProductCollection
- - $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
- Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection
- - See Below

**prepareProductCollection**

```
public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
{
    $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addUrlRewrite($this->getCurrentCategory()->getId());

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

    return $this;
}
```

So: 
Add the price info to the collection:

- ->addMinimalPrice()
- ->addFinalPrice()
- ->addTaxPercents()

You may only need ->addFinalPrice(), I'm not sure what data you are looking for.